# How to Write a Join for a M-M-M Relationship

Tags: mysql, database, join, many-to-many, inner-join

I am working with an API where only certain whitelisted domains are able to access our services. Each domain can use a multitude of services (we have more than one), and each domain will have a unique access token related to each service.

Here is the structure of the tables I have set up:

[image: DB Table Relationships]

Basically, there is a M2M relationship between Whitelist_Domains and Services, as well as a M2M relationship between Services and Tokens.

I want to retrieve "TOKEN" from the Tokens table, and the information I provided with is Whitelist_Domains.DOMAIN, and Services.ID.

I am having trouble generating a SQL query that will return the correct information though.

Any help would greatly be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what is your issue.? what problem you faced.?

Comment: It seems like you figured out the hard bit, and then got stuck on the easy bit!

Comment: The keyword to search for is: INNER JOIN: That join only returns the records which comply with all your conditions.